# Team services pick list custom field limit

Tags: azure-devops

I am customizing a field in team services (visual studio online) and i have a picklist which contains more  than 300 items.

But right now the allowed number of items is only 128

Is there a way to adjust this limit?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. For more information, you can check [this](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/work/import-process/differences#object-limits) article.

> **Object limits**
>
> When customizing a process template for import, limit the number of
>   the following objects you define.
>
> 64 WITs
>
> 256 fields per WIT
>
> 16 workflow states per WIT
>
> 16 person-name fields
>
> 1024 rules per field
>
> **128 pick list values per field**
>
> 512 fields per account/collection
>
> 5 portfolio backlogs
>
> 32 categories